# How do I restrict access to forum?

Tags: 8, users

How do I give restrict access to forum?

I am using the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) and the [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) modules, and they work fine for individual node/forum topic, but I need this for forum, as the [Forum access](https://www.drupal.org/project/forum_access) module did in Drupal 7.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Pierre.Vriens. Thanks for reply. I have not used group module yet. I will definitely look in to it.

Comment: The question is still not acceptable because the only way to achieve that is with a module. So, or we recommend a module, or we tell you how to do that writing a custom module. Don't expect the later, if you don't show any effort in writing a custom module; the former is off-topic for us.

Comment: Maybe you want to **[ask your question again](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)** on **[this site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)**?

Comment: Thanks @Pierre for suggestion. Now i got way to solve this problem. I got a module. https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite. which able to solve my problem. I was thought to post this answer but question was already closed.